Google Apps Script: Form Options Not Updating Despite Correct Logs
I'm working on a Google Apps Script that dynamically updates the options in a Google Form based on responses collected in a linked Google Sheet. The script runs without errors, and the execution logs show the correct results (e.g., 4 PM session is full, and only 7 PM session should remain available). However, even after running the script and refreshing the form, the 4 PM option is still visible in the Google Form.
What I'm asking for:

Has anyone encountered this issue where the form doesn’t reflect the updated options after running the script?
Are there any potential issues with caching, permissions, or the setChoices method in Google Apps Script that I may have missed?
Any suggestions on additional steps to debug this issue or ensure the form updates properly?

Here's My script
function autoLimitBySession() {
  const FORM_ID = "1Gab3Obs0xooR6tmnlE0tPDOWgK5iY1jeQHDjCb6373M"; // Replace with your Google Form ID
  const LIMIT_PER_SESSION = 1; // Limit per session
  const SESSION_COLUMN = 7; // Column G: "Choose 1 Music Party Session"
  const SHEET_NAME = "Form Responses 1"; // Replace with your sheet name

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  let count4PM = 0;
  let count7PM = 0;

  // Count responses
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const session = data[i][SESSION_COLUMN - 1];
    if (session.includes("4pm (Limited to 10 Kids)")) count4PM++;
    if (session.includes("7pm (Limited to 10 Kids)")) count7PM++;
  }

  Logger.log(`Current counts: 4 PM = ${count4PM}, 7 PM = ${count7PM}`);
  Logger.log(`Remaining slots: 4 PM = ${LIMIT_PER_SESSION - count4PM}, 7 PM = ${LIMIT_PER_SESSION - count7PM}`);

  const form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);

  if (count4PM >= LIMIT_PER_SESSION && count7PM >= LIMIT_PER_SESSION) {
    form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
    form.setCustomClosedFormMessage("All sessions are fully booked. Thank you!");
    Logger.log("Form closed: All sessions are full.");
    return;
  }

  const items = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
  items.forEach(item => {
    const title = item.getTitle();
    if (title.includes("Choose 1 Music Party Session")) {
      const sessionItem = item.asMultipleChoiceItem();
      const choices = [];

      if (count4PM < LIMIT_PER_SESSION) {
        choices.push(sessionItem.createChoice("4pm (Limited to 10 Kids)"));
      }
      if (count7PM < LIMIT_PER_SESSION) {
        choices.push(sessionItem.createChoice("7pm (Limited to 10 Kids)"));
      }

      if (choices.length === 0) {
        choices.push(sessionItem.createChoice("All sessions are fully booked"));
      }

      Logger.log(`Updated choices: ${choices.map(choice => choice.getValue())}`);
      sessionItem.setChoices(choices);
    }
  });
}

What I’ve tried:

Manually running the script and refreshing the form (both with Ctrl + F5 and using incognito mode).
Verified that the FORM_ID is correct and matches the intended Google Form.
Checked the Google Form’s question title and ensured it matches the script's logic:
Added detailed logging to confirm that the script correctly processes the data and updates the options dynamically.

What am I expecting:

Remove option for 4pm from google form if it's been selected and submitted for at least 1 time.
Remove option for 7pm from google form if it's been selected and submitted for at least 1 time.
Closed the google form if both reach maximum limit.


I want to confirm that this code is being called using a trigger, onFormSubmit()?

 const LIMIT_PER_SESSION = 1; // Limit per session Isn't the limit per session = 10. viz (Limited to 10 Kids)

@Babanana Does that make a difference?

@Tedinoz I tried to replicate the issue on my end and created some sort of project like what he has, I was just confirming because the issue he specifically said is not happening on my end. This is just a long shot comment since we got different result, though there are some caching issues it is far from what he is experiencing hence the question the point is actually getting how he set it up, I am wondering if what the issue is coming from the fact that the code is only being called once.

@Babanana what value did you use for “limit per session”?

@Tedinoz I tried with "1", the issue I am experiencing was from the adjustment after the count has been initially run, options adjust as well.

@Babanana There's no point in running LIMIT_PER_SESSION = 1; it must be run as = 10. Change this, and the script works.

The script actually works for me when I try it that is why I am asking long shot questions to OP that might be the cause of the issue. I am experiencing some issue with the code when I tried it, regardless of the limit number but it is far from what the OP is experiencing

@Babanana Hmm. Like to share?

David Tai - have you resolved your problem?
